# How to add a point at the end of an abbreviation with biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex

In the examples of `biblatex-sbl`, there are several examples of abbreviations with the command `\printbiblist`. My problem: how to add a point only at the end of a lexicon article in such list? The journals and series, however, should end without a point For instance, I want this:

> EAE Encyclopaedia Aethiopica. Edited by Siegbert Uhlig. 4 vols. Wiesbaden,2003–2010.
>
> OCA Orientalia Christiana Analecta

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@mvlexicon{EAE,
editor = {Uhlig, Siegbert},
title = {Encyclopaedia Aethiopica},
shorttitle = {EAE},
volumes = {4},
location = {Wiesbaden},
date = {2003/2010},
shorthand = {EAE}
}
@inlexicon{Gert.2007,
author = {Gert, Jaap},
title = {Art. Kebrast},
pages = {282},
volume = {3},
xref = {EAE}
}

@incollection{Ab.2005,
 author = {Ab, Tom},
 date = {2005},
 title = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 shorttitle = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 editor = {Zenk, Raul},
 pages = {132--134},
 location = {Rom},
 booktitle = {Studi},
series = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
 shortseries = {OCA},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

genannt\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{Gert.2007}.} oder\footcite{{Ab.2005}.}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of  `\footnote{Vgl.: \cite{Gert.2007}.}` and `\footcite{{Ab.2005}.}` I would use `\autocite[Vgl.:][]{Gert.2007}` and `\autocite{Ab.2005}` (possibly together with the `biblatex` option `autocite=footnote` - depending on the style setting it might not be necessary to specify this explicitly if it is the default) or at the very least `\footcite`.

Comment: Just to clarify: Do you you also want a full stop at the end of "OCA Orientalia Christiana Analecta"?

Comment: Another question: What about the end of a normal entry in the bibliography? Do you want a full stop there as well?

Comment: As a heads up SBL has changed their style on these. There will be periods at the end, but also the format will be changed to the same as the bibliography. See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/94. The next release of `biblatex-sbl` will reflect this, but I haven't implemented it yet.

Comment: @moewe, according to SBL latest requirements, OCA would not have the period at the end. Only EAE would. The difficulty is that the OP doesn't quite want SBL style, just something similar…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the period at the end with a simple patch to the `abbreviations` driver:

```
\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{abbreviations}
  {\usebibmacro{bibentrycite}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibentrycite}%
   \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}
  {}
  {}
```

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents} 
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}

@mvlexicon{EAE,
editor = {Uhlig, Siegbert},
title = {Encyclopaedia Aethiopica},
shorttitle = {EAE},
volumes = {4},
location = {Wiesbaden},
date = {2003/2010},
shorthand = {EAE}
}
@inlexicon{Gert.2007,
author = {Gert, Jaap},
title = {Art. Kebrast},
pages = {282},
volume = {3},
xref = {EAE}
}

@incollection{Ab.2005,
 author = {Ab, Tom},
 date = {2005},
 title = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 shorttitle = {Gǝ’ǝz Anaphora},
 editor = {Zenk, Raul},
 pages = {132--134},
 location = {Rom},
 booktitle = {Studi},
series = {Orientalia Christiana Analecta},
 shortseries = {OCA},
}

\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[autostyle=true,german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,ibidtracker=false,idemtracker=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibdriver{abbreviations}
  {\usebibmacro{bibentrycite}}
  {\usebibmacro{bibentrycite}%
   \renewcommand*{\finentrypunct}{\addperiod}}
  {}
  {}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill
genannt \autocite[Vgl.][]{Gert.2007}. oder \autocite{Ab.2005}.
\printbiblist{abbreviations}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]